# why I'm getting this return value" jQuery.fn.init [input.search-city, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(1)]"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, input

when I write the code like this I get this return value: jQuery.fn.init [input.search-city, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(1)],

```
 var $y = $('.search-city').on('change', function() {
         
        return $('.search-city').val();
    });  
    console.log($y);
```

but when I write like this

```
 $('.search-city').on('change', function() {

        console.log($('.search-city').val());//morocco 
    });
```

I get what I want, but I need this value as a return value to use it in my code , how can I fixe this problem.

Comment: what is '.search-city'  ? is a input text, input select or what?

Comment: yes input search

Comment: `let $val = "";
var $y = $('.search-city').on('change', function() {      
   $val = $('.search-city').val();
});  

console.log($val); `

Comment: Fatima Mazhit is not working

Answer (score 0):

you can simply using this

```js
$('.search-city').on('change', function(){
    let val_ = $(this).val(); // get the value and store at val_
    if( val_.length ){// if the value are not empty
      console.log(`the value is : ${val_}`);
    }else{// its empty, no value
      console.log(`value are empty`);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="search-city" type="search" placeholder="search something" />
```

Comment: I need this value to put it in a variable  which is out of my finction , not to put it in a console.log

Comment: i think you need to learn more about javascript. i recomended this site : https://www.w3schools.com/js/